# Can I apply for a US visa under a different citizenship than I did the last time?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

Asking this out of sheer curiosity for now. 
I am facing the prospect of acquiring a second citizenship, and while researching the benefits of that decision I bumped into something interesting.
For my current citizenship, the US issues B1/B2 visas with a maximum validity period of 3 years (2 years in most cases). Obviously, this doesn't feel great, especially considering some African countries get 5 or even 10 years, and we only get 3.
However, for the citizenship I seek to acquire, the maximum validity would actually be 10 years!
The question is, can I legally do this? Is it ok for me to apply for a visa as a citizen of another country, if I have previously had 2 visas issued under my current citizenship? I do not intend to renounce my current citizenship, if that matters at all. Will I face a higher chance of refusal?

Comment: Why is it a problem if some African countries are given 5 or ten years? Are Africans not deserving of also getting the _good_ things of this world? Do Africans have to be at the bottom of the totem pole in everything?

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie Oh, I am terribly sorry if I sounded racist. I was pointing towards the fact that the countries in question have poorer economies, lower wages, higher crime rates than my country, also accompanied by widespread corruption. Those are objective figures that every country would factor into its immigration/tourism policies. Yet, due to some political bullshit we get less visa duration than those countries. I just feel that's unfair, that's all.

Comment: That is another condescending and bigoted statement which you may not realize. Africa is not monolithic and I bet there are African countries which beat your country whichever it is on some of those metrics and that is an objective statement. But you surely are entitled to your opinion. The USA is the best to know which countries citizens to offer long term visas to.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie To put it in other way, am I the one who feels discriminated here. African countries were just a good reference point. I have no problem with Africans getting 5 and 10 year visas, especially considering my stepfather is from one of those countries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, it's totally fine, there's nothing illegal or wrong about changing or adding citizenships.  Just be sure to state the facts if asked about other citizenships, previous visas, name changes etc as applicable.

Source: I have had ESTAs for the US with two different citizenships.  No problems.

Comment: Would I have to turn in both passports though? Normally, when replacing a visa, they would want to stamp a "cancelled without prejudice" on the former visa, which in that case would be in a passport of different nationality...?
Would I be eligible to apply without an interview, under the same rules as I would for my first nationality?

Comment: @user4551 there's no advantage to getting your current visa cancelled. Just apply for your next visa with your new citizenship when the need arises.

Comment: No problem at all just make sure you state the facts when you apply the second time, I have had 2 visas with two different citizenships, no problem whatsoever